# how to read response from node.js server in android app

Tags: android, node.js, retrofit2, response

i have android app where i have login mhetod using retrofit where i send login and password,server on node.js get my log and pas and send me in app some token. android app doesn`t get token. I think its because i don`t know how to server should send information.

**my send post mhetod**

```
private fun LoginBtn(apiClient: ApiClient, login_btn: Button, sessionManager: SessionManager) {
    login_btn.setOnClickListener {

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {

            Log.d("MainActivity", "test ")
            apiClient.getApiService()
                .login("login", "password") //
                .enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                        // Error logging in
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "onFailure: $t")
                    }

                    override fun onResponse(
                        call: Call<LoginResponse>,
                        response: Response<LoginResponse>
                    ) {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "onResponse: ")

                        val loginResponse = response.body()


                        if (loginResponse?.statusCode == 200) {
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "onResponse: ${loginResponse.authToken}")
                            sessionManager.saveAuthToken(loginResponse.authToken)
                        } else {
                            // Error logging in
                            Log.d("MainActivity", "onResponse: ")

                        }
                    }
                })

        }
    }
}
```

after login mhetod send pas and log, in mhetod `.enqueue` trigered `onFailure` with information
ure: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

**my server code**

```
app.post('/login', function(request, response){

    console.log(request.body.login);
    console.log(request.body.password);
    
        response.writeHead(200,accessToken,refreshToken)
        // response.writeHead(200,"hellowwwwwww")
        response.cookie(200,"hellow","kostya")
        response.write("seccess")
        response.end

});
```

maybe in node server send respounse by another method

Comment: have you tried to `response.end()` ?

Comment: in what sense? i bad know node.js sorry

Comment: I was reffering to put the last parenthesis to the sentence. `response.end` -> `response.end()`